# Cannot compile simple file that includes \startsection command

Tags: sectioning, context

I thought to give a try in ConTeXt, and so I tried to compile the following:

```
\starttext
\startsection[title={Testing ConTeXt}]
  This is my {\em first} ConTeXt document.
\stopsection
\stoptext
```

However, I get the following error

```
! Undefined control sequence. l.2 \startsection
                  [title={Testing ConTeXt}] ?
```

Comment: What did you actually run: this looks like a perfectly-normal ConTeXt document to me and runs fine.

Comment: Are you generating the document with `texexec`? Then I think you're using ConTeXt MkII, try with `context filename.tex` instead, then you'll be using MkIV

Comment: I am using `TeXworks` as an editor and I try to compile my document by selecting ConteXt (pdfTeX) from the drop-down menu

Comment: Use *ConTeXt (LuaTeX)* instead.

Comment: That was the solution! But why I need to use `ConTeXt (LuaTeX)`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The current ConTeXt, MkIV, works only with LuaTeX, so in TeXworks needs 'ConTeXt (LuaTeX)'. The older ConTeXt MkII is still available and works with pdfTeX or XeTeX only. However, as well as the change of engine and new functionality, the ConTeXt team have altered a number of interfaces in developing MkIV. In particular, MkII didn't have the idea of `\startsection` ... `\stopsection`, but only had 'stand alone' sectioning commands (much like LaTeX).

Unless you have existing MkII documents, you are strongly advised to use MkIV.

Comment: I think that the need to mention that you need to compile your document with `LuaLaTeX`, in order to avoid future misunderstanding

Comment: Perhaps you want to add that `\start...\stopsection` is preferred over `\section` because it is friendlier towards the generation of standardised PDF.  Also, I don't think that even for old documents you should use MKII.  If you have the chance to convert them easily to MKIV, do it.

Answer (score 8):

The latest version of ConTeXt is MkIV, and `\startsection` is only available in MkIV: http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/startsection

I'm not too familiar with ConTeXt, but when you choose *ConTeXt (pdfTeX)* in TeXworks, the PDF is generated using a program called `texexec`, which I think is locked to using ConTeXt MkII. On the other hand, when you choose *ConTeXt (LuaTeX)*, the document is generated with a script called `context`, and this will use the newer ConTeXt MkIV, see http://wiki.contextgarden.net/context